# Umbraco Installation Problem On IIS7

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista, umbraco

I'm trying to install Umbraco locally on Vista (IIS7) and ASP.NET35 - I have used the web.config for IIS7 and aspnet35 shown on the umbraco forums but still getting this IIS error.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. Detailed Error Information 

Module IIS Web Core Notification BeginRequest Handler Not yet determined 

Error Code 0x80070021 Config Error This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. 

Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false". 

Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\umbraco\web.config


Requested URL http://localhost:80/umbraco/install/ 

Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\umbraco\install\ Logon Method Not yet determined Logon User Not yet determined Config Source

185: </modules> 186: <handlers> 187: <!-- Asp.net 3.5 handlers-->
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me - just keep looking at what the section is that's causing the error and change the config file section to allow - had to run through this three times unlocking various sections

http://www.methodicmadness.com/2009/01/http-error-50019-this-configuration.html

Comment: This worked for me I had to enable Allow for Handlers and Modules.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the config file section in error for me was the one which registered the adobe extension.

```
 <!-- Adobe AIR mime type     -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
    </staticContent>
```

Once I commented this out then the site came up perfectly.

I am using Windows Vista with IIS7 (v6 SP2)

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, checked all permissions, tried changing the app pool to classic mode, nothing worked apart from commenting out the Adobe Air section.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Umbraco 4 Succesfully** on my Vista Ultimate x64 box. as well as my Windows 2008 x64 server.

Make sure you do the following...

1. Make sure that the website application pool is running in [classic mode under IIS7](http://www.newguid.net/blog/post/2008/12/03/Run-webapplication-on-IIS7-(Vista)-in-classic-mode.aspx), a [umbraco forum post](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst1245_A-version-compatible-with-Windows-Server-2008--ASPNET-35.aspx) about it.
2. Make sure that the [NTFS file permissions](http://www.techduke.com/2007/07/06/protecting-your-stuff-ntfs-permissions/) are set correctly so IIS can access the correct files.
3. Make sure your web.config file is valid and can be passed. [online parser (copy and paste)](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_validate.asp)

Comment: How do I know what sections need write / read permissions?  Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: IIS7 and umbraco needs permission to access all of its files. It depends what account IIS7 is operating under (so the directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\umbraco\\). Try and add ASP.NET/LocalService/NetworkService accounts in the ntfs file permissions. If that doesn't work try Everybody (for security don't set this permanently for production servers)

Comment: Lime Elijah said, setting 'Full Control' to 'Everyone' fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

How did you do the install? It is *strongly* recommened you install Umbraco via the Microsoft Web Platform Installer (webpi) - http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/default.aspx

The problem though was likely because you weren't running the app in the Classic app pool mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear from the error - one of the configuration sections set in web.config is locked on the parent/server level. Check your applicaitonHost.config to see what section that is set in Umbraco/web.config cannot be overriden (it has overrideModeDefault="Deny"), then either unlock that section (if you have permissions) for the website or remove the configuration in question from web.config.

Answer (score 0):

There are some custom configuration sections used for configuring Examine and various other elements of Umbraco, and the relevant `<section>` declarations in the web.config need `requirePermission="false"` to be set (which they're not in the default .NET3.5 config).
Check that `requirePermission="false"` is present on all `<section>` elements, then try again.

HTH,

Benjamin

Answer (score -1):

Check the IIS application pool .NET framework version - it should be using the latest .NET framework. If not, set it to the latest version of the .NET framework.

Answer (score -1):

This helped me 
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i (concern 64Bit)

forum -
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/12506-HTTP-error-50019-Internal-Server-Error